# Using Include-Exclude Logic in SQL

Tags: sql, db2, cobol

I have following employee data table.
I'm trying to create a select query based on following logic:
if status = 'X', display only records having status = 'X'
else if (status not = 'X' and status = spaces), display all records

I have tried all possible combinations to get the result but failed. Could anyone please suggest me how to perform this?

```
EmpNo  | Name  |Status   | Age 
================================
11     | Aron  | A       | 25
22     | Barry | X       | 26
33     | Carol | A       | 27
44     | Danny | I       | 28
55     | Emmy  | X       | 29
66     | Fanny | I       | 30
77     | Garry | A       | 25
88     | Harry | X       | 26
```

Comment: im not sure what this has to do with COBOL.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @saggingrufus... I ll be using this query in a COBOL-DB2 handler/module. There4 mentioned the tag :)

Comment: So, what would be the expected output, given your sample data, and why?

Comment: Expected output-
Suppose..
If given input to the select query is age =26 and status = 'X', only 2nd and last row should be fetched....
But if input given is status='spaces' I need to display all the records (this will include 2nd and last rows too)....
Why? Coz I'm creating an employee detail search screen in cics which will take the given input from online screen and fetch the result from table....

Comment: the only way this is COBOL related is if you are doing a SELECT * and then manipulating the result set in COBOL. everything you mentioned so far can be handled in your SQL

Comment: @saggingrufus.....I mentioned the COBOL tag just to giv a background that I ll be using d query in COBOL pgm. The real qstn is how dis query can be written ? 
Adding to dis,even if I write 2 separate queries wer status ='X' & status ='spaces' , I also need to include age & name in my query too......
Ther4 I need my query to work in following logic (pseudo code):

Select * from employee-table 
where
(if age = '25',select only rows having age 25 else all rows)
and
 (if status ='X',select only status=X rows else all rows)
and 
(If name ='Garry', select only name=Garry rows else all rows)
End-sql

Comment: @KaranBagwe change the tag to SQL if you have an SQL question.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do cannot be achieved in a single query. You'll need to write multiple select queries depending on `Where` conditions.

In Cobol, move your input to working storage host variables WS-AGE and WS-STATUS. Then write your queries as:

```
If Age > Zeroes and Status > Spaces
    Select EmpNo, Name, Age, Status
        into :host-variable1, :hv2, :hv3, :hv4
        from Table
        Where Age=:WS-AGE
          and Status=:WS-STATUS
Else
    If Age > Zeroes
       Select EmpNo, Name, Age, Status
        into :host-variable1, :hv2, :hv3, :hv4
        from Table
        Where Age=:WS-AGE
    Else
       Select EmpNo, Name, Age, Status
        into :host-variable1, :hv2, :hv3, :hv4
        from Table
    End-if
End-if
```